# Multiple print copies of same report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have SSRS report created(Sales Order), client want multiple print copies at one shot,
like, When user clicks on print button, it should print 3 copies,
First copy should have header "Base Copy"
Second should have header "Copy1"
third should have header "Copy2" .

Please guide me how to achieve this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an easy thing to produce as I've not come across this ability.

As a workaround I think the best way is to produce one report that has the same report copied 3 times one under the other. But instead of using a header create a textbox that simulates a header. Then use the page break to option in the textbox to force a new page.